# Como achar o diretório correto de um arquivo usando python?

Tags: python

estou criando um programa que ache o diretório de um arquivo. Mas o problema é que eu até acho porém não é o caminho completo.

Código:

```
import os 

diretorio = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(("index.py")))
print(diretorio)
```

Saída: C:\Users\luoll\Documents\Curso_Python

**Caminho completo**= C:\Users\luoll\Documents\Curso_Python\Projetos\QRcode_generator\index.py

**Usando essa função ele só vai até a pasta **Curso_Python**, como posso chegar no caminho real do arquivo "index.py"???**

Comment: talvez o que deseja é a função `os.path.abspath`.

Comment: Obrigadooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando a função [`abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Segue um exemplo:

```
import os

diretorio = os.path.abspath('main.py')
print(diretorio)
# C:\Users\foo\development\python\main.py
```

Segundo a documentação:

#### os.path.abspath(path)

> Retorna uma versão normalizada do diretório do arquivo passado como
> parâmetro.
>
> Na maioria das plataformas, isso é equivalente a chamar a função
> normpath() da seguinte forma: *normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))*.